# How update table automatically with @DynamicUpdate and @Transactional

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I would like to update a column entry automatically when the application start. To do that, I've a simple model with @DynamicUpdate anotation :

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User implements Serializable {

int id;
String firstName;
String SecondName;
String Maths;

}
```

to update Maths, I've created 2 methods in its service with @Transactional anotation:

```
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    @Transactional
    public void updateMaths() {
        Integer i = 580168;
        calculateMathsById(i);

    }

public void calculateMathsById(int id){
        User user = userRepository.getById(id);
        int number = calculateNumber(user);
        model.setMaths(user);
        modelRepository.update(user);
    }
```

and finally, here's the simple repository method with @Modifying anotation :

```
    @Modifying
    @Query("update User  set maths = (:maths) where id = (:id)")
    public void updateUser(@Param("maths") Integer maths, @Param("id") Integer id);
```

Everything seems to be correct, the application start but nothing appends. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You aren't calling that method but just the `update` method. Also `updateUser` basically defeats the purpose of `@DynamicUpdate`.

Comment: consider using spring life cycle hooks

Comment: 1. use `findById` not `getById` 2. what is calling the `updateMaths` method? If you only have this method and nothing is calling it at startup, then exactly that will happen, nothing.

Comment: you're true. I supposed that the @Transactional was able to update automatically and start the method. So I've added @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) and now it works! Thanks for your help!